# Configure Docker as a daemon and run containers

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-desktop, docker-daemon

I used dockerd --register-service to register my Docker daemon on windows.

Now I want a GitLab container to run when the system is booted (before login). What settings are needed for this?

Here is my windows-daemon-option.json:

```
{
    "allow-nondistributable-artifacts": ["host_port_or_cidr|redacted"],
    "authorization-plugins": [],
    "bridge": "none",
    "cluster-advertise": "",
    "cluster-store": "",
    "data-root": "path|redacted",
    "debug": true,
    "default-ulimits": {},
    "disable-legacy-registry": false,
    "dns": ["ip|redacted"],
    "dns-opts": [],
    "dns-search": ["domain|redacted"],
    "exec-opts": [],
    "experimental": true,
    "fixed-cidr": "redacted",
    "graph": "deprecated|redacted",
    "group": "",
    "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:80"],
    "insecure-registries": ["host_port_or_cidr|redacted"],
    "labels": [],
    "live-restore": true,
    "log-driver": "",
    "log-level": "",
    "max-concurrent-downloads": 3,
    "max-concurrent-uploads": 5,
    "metrics-addr":"endpoint|redacted",
    "mtu": 0,
    "pidfile": "redacted",
    "raw-logs": false,
    "registry-mirrors": ["registry|redacted"],
    "shutdown-timeout": 15,
    "storage-driver": "",
    "storage-opts": [],
    "swarm-default-advertise-addr": "endpoint|redacted",
    "tlscacert": "redacted",
    "tlscert": "redacted",
    "tlskey": "redacted",
    "tlsverify": true
}
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**

I have created a container, of course.

```
docker run `
  --detach `
  --hostname gitlab.mydomain.de `
  --ip 192.168.178.35 `
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 `
  --name gitlab `
  --restart always `
  --volume $env:GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab `
  --volume $env:GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab `
  --volume $env:GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab `
  --shm-size 256m `
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.4.0-ce.0 `
```

Comment: You should just be able to create a container with `docker run`. Set a restart policy of "always" (`docker run --restart=always ...`) and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already created a container.

Comment: Setting a restart policy of `Always` on the container means that Docker will start it for you when your computer boots (as long as you have Docker set up to start before you log in). If Docker doesn't start until after you login, you have a different question.